# dtsinstall.exe does not deploy packages

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, dts

1. I created SSIS project solution in VS2008.
2. I created 5 packages and deployed them to SSIS Storage succesfully.
3. I executed 4 packages successfully.
4. I leave SQL server few days alone (holiday!).
5. I open SSIS solution and made little change in 5th package. Save and Build  solution.
6. I execute an deploy (same way as before, using dtsinstall.exe ..) **Change does not apply**.
7. I deleted package from SSIS storage.
8. I Execute deploy again.. but.. **package is missing**..

*Deploying is allways successfull

**why packages are not loaded to server ?**

What am i missing ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

DTSInstaller.exe consumes a file called with an extension of SSISDeploymentManifest

The contents of it look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<DTSDeploymentManifest 
    GeneratedBy="HOME\administrator"
    GeneratedFromProjectName="SSISHackAndSlash"
    GeneratedDate="2010-04-30T21:19:08.6336677-05:00"
    AllowConfigurationChanges="true">
        <Package>Package.dtsx</Package>
        <Package>Package2.dtsx</Package>
        <Package>Package7.dtsx</Package>
</DTSDeploymentManifest>
```

That file defines the universe of SSIS packages the DTSInstaller will operate upon.

It *sounds* like the manifest file you are using does not have match the list of packages in your project. You can right click on the project itself and select Properties, Deployment tab and change the value of `CreateDeploymentUtility` from false to true.

Now when you right click on your project to build, or deploy, your bin\Deployment folder will contain a new version of the manifest file. Double click on that and you should have all the desired packages ready for installation.

An alternate approach, would be to use your manifest file but have PowerShell generate the deploy commands. Advantage of that is you can audit what's being deployed versus the black box of DTSInstaller.exe [PowerShell, dtutil, SSISDeployManifest - How to deploy SSIS packages with PowerShell](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/05/powershell-dtutil-ssisdeploymanifest.html)

Comment: I already have manifest file created by deployment property, but i will try the powershell approach to see whats problem, thank you

Comment: Look at the contents of the manifest - does it have the package listed in it?

Comment: Yes it contains my 5 packages.